# Java encryption project (java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Tags: java, exception, encryption, project, indexoutofboundsexception

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Oppish_Coder2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz";
        String ss = "aeiouy";

        System.out.println("Enter line to encrypt: ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        String uncoded = sc.next();

        System.out.println("Encrypted line: ");

            for (int i = 0; i < uncoded.length(); i++){

                for (int ii = 0; ii < s.length(); ii++){

                    if (uncoded.charAt(i) == s.charAt(ii)){
                        System.out.print(uncoded.charAt(i) + "op ");
                    }
                    else {
                        for (int iii = 0; iii < ss.length(); iii++){
                            if (uncoded.charAt(i) == ss.charAt(ii)){
                                System.out.print(uncoded.charAt(i) + " ");
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

I've been working on this project for fun on and off but recently I feel as if I'm very close to getting it to work however an error is being thrown and I'm not sure about how to fix it. The purpose of the code is to add an "op " to the end of any consonants and a " " to the end of vowels. This was inspired by a childhood way of talking in code so only you and a friend knew what the other was saying. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: I don't think your code, as posted, is anywhere close to working. Please take some time to consider the logic of what you are trying to do and fix your loops accordingly. I would recommend reading a tutorial that covers the `break` and `continue` statements.

Comment: In your third for loop you are comparing `uncoded.charAt(i) == ss.charAt(ii)` instead of `uncoded.charAt(i) == ss.charAt(iii)`. Moreover that loop shouldn't be nested. Word of advice; use distinct letters as loop variables.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop so many times for checking whether a character in your uncoded string is a vowel or consonant.

I've simplified your program by using `String.indexOf` method. You just check whether the letters in your uncoded string are present in the `vowels` string or `consonants` string.

Here it is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Oppish_Coder2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz";
        String vowels = "aeiouy";

        System.out.println("Enter line to encrypt: ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String uncoded = sc.next();

        System.out.println("Encrypted line: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < uncoded.length(); i++) {
            char c = uncoded.charAt(i);
            if (consonants.indexOf(c)>-1) {
                System.out.print(c + "op ");
            } else if (vowels.indexOf(c)>-1) {
                System.out.print(c + " ");
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!